# Calculating Count For Difficult Pivot Table With Merged Lines in Sisense

Tags: pivot, sisense

I want to calculate count of ORDER_DISP_NO for each DISPLAY_SKU like count(ORDER_DISP_NO) group by DISPLAY_SKU. For example it should be 6 for first row and 2 for third row. Please see screenshot [image]

Looks like I cannot use DupCount() in this case but how can I get correct data in the last column?

Comment: Have you tried simple count(order_disp_no)

Comment: Yes of course I tried count() and dupCount(), the same result. You can see result of dupCount() on the screenshot.

Comment: I see. Will need to look at some sample data. I think this count might be right based on your order display number for each sku,description,commod_code.